# How to display multiple row records of similar ID's in single row?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables user and work. Work table has multiple user's work experience.I have to retrieve most recent 2 companies on the basis of start date.

**Conditions :**

1.If Work Table has multiple user's Id's records, retrieve recent 2 records and show in single row (e.g. User_id = 1)

2.If Work Table has single record is most recent companies record and second record should be "NULL"(e.g. user_id = 3).

```
user
user_id  First_name  Last_name
  1        AAA         BBB
  2        PPP         QQQ
  3        SSS         RRR

work
user_id recent_company position start_year end_year
    1        ABC          CCC     2014       2015
    1        PQR          DDD     2013       2014
    1        MNO          EEE     2012       2013
    1        MNO          EEE     0000       0000
    2        XYZ          TTT     2008       2009
    2        IJK          MMM     2005       2008
    3        QRS          ZZZ     2001       2002
```

I've tried for most recent company record 1 :

```
select u.user_id,u.first_name,u.last_name,uw.recent_company1,uw.position1,uw.start_year,uw.end_year from muser u
left join
(SELECT user_id,recent_company,position,MAX(start_year) as start_year,end_year 
FROM work 
group by user_id 
order by user_id) uw ON u.user_id =uw.user_id
```

Result of my query for 1st recent company on start year basis:

```
user_id  First_name  Last_name     recent_company1   
  1        AAA         BBB            ABC                          
  2        PPP         QQQ            XYZ                           
  3        SSS         RRR            QRS             

position1    start_year1    end_year1
   CCC         2014           2015
   TTT         2008           2009
   ZZZ         2001           2002
```

Required Output for both 1st and 2nd recent company on start_year basis:

```
user_id  First_name  Last_name   recent_company1   position1    
  1        AAA         BBB          ABC             CCC                 
  2        PPP         QQQ          XYZ             TTT                
  3        SSS         RRR          QRS             ZZZ                 

start_year1    end_year1
    2014         2015
    2008         2009
    2001         2002

   recent_company2   position2   start_year2    end_year2
      PQR               DDD         2013          2014
      IJK               MMM         2005          2008
      NULL              NULL        NULL          NULL
```